# Is there an error with pandas.Dataframe.ewm calculation or I am wrong?

Tags: python, pandas

I choose the recursive option in order to calculate weighted moving average starting from the latest calculated value.

According to [Documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ewm.html) :

> When adjust=False, the exponentially weighted function is calculated
> recursively:

> `y0 = x0`

> `y(t) = (1-alpha) * y(t-1) + alpha * x(t)`

So I have the following code :

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 5, 8, 9],
                   })
alpha=0.5
df['ewm'] = df['col1'].ewm(alpha, adjust=False).mean()
```

which gives :

```
>>> df
   col1       ewm
0     1  1.000000
1     1  1.000000
2     2  1.666667
3     3  2.555556
4     3  2.851852
5     5  4.283951
6     8  6.761317
7     9  8.253772
```

The problem is that it's not corresponding to following mathematical calculations :

- y0 = x0 = **1**
- y1 = (1-0.5) * y0 + 0.5 * x1 = 0.5 + 0.5 = **1**
- y2 = (1-0.5) * y1 + 0.5 * x2 = 0.5 + 0.5 * 2 = **1.5**
- y3 = (1-0.5) * y2 + 0.5 * x3 = 0.5 * 1.5 + 0.5 * 3 = 0.75 + 1.5 = **2.25**
  ...

We do not have the same values. What's wrong ?

Comment: You forgot to set alpha=alpha or alpha=0.5?

`df['ewm'] = df['col1'].ewm(alpha=alpha, adjust=False).mean()`

Comment: it works but it's strange like alpha was first defined to 0.5

Comment: They mean that `alpha` needs to be a named keyword. You used your `alpha` variable, but you need to pass it as `alpha=alpha`.

Comment: Ok I understand now, this is not clearly said in doc

Comment: This question is not particular to Pandas' `ewm`, but rather a general Python problem. I'd go as far to say it's a general programming problem that requires developer to read the doc and to pass the params correctly.

Comment: I agree for reading the doc, this is what I am doing generally. But this was not clearly exposed : https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ewm.html named parameters are used in examples but it's not explicitly said that this is absolutely necessary with no other means. So for the reader it's a guess game

Comment: Right I would say a general programming problem. If you aren't passing the parameters by position you have to pass it with it's keyword.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I read in comments parameters should be named.

Documentation do not exposed this fact clearly.

One must be careful because no exception is raised when using no named arguments, but calculations are false.

Comment: Just to clarify further, the params don't need to be named unless you are using them out of order. The 1st param is `com`, so `ewm(0.5)` means `ewm(com=0.5)`. Since `alpha` is the 4th param, it needs to be named as `ewm(alpha=0.5)`.